# The basic idea of regression with multiple data

Tags: regression, logistic

I am learning the tool of regression. In the text, I was introduced with the measurement of the diameter of different spheres of the same material many times and estimate the volume with formula. In this case, the variable X is the diameter and the Y is the resulting volume. It is easy to understand. But I was given some data in marketing with X refers to the sale price, Y is the customers' response (Y=1, means a good product, Y=0 means a bad product). The data is collecting by questionnaire to many customers' buying the product in different places so at different prices. However, for those customers who are buying the product at the same price, the response could vary. We observe that for constant X, there is some percentage of responses with Y=1 and some percentage of responses with Y=0. It is confusing that in this case, can we fit the X, Y with a line or curve? In the diameter measuring example, we measure different objects with a different diameter so all (X, Y) pair are different, it lays out clear points set for fitting. But for the marketing example, so many data pair (X, Y) are referring to the same point, says I have (X=3, Y=1) and (X=3, Y=0) at the same times, what does it mean in the concept of regression?

Comment: Are you trying to fit lines or curves by drawing them by hand, or are you using a software package?

Comment: I am using matlab to fit the data.

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-data-with-generalized-linear-models.html

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. I think that helps me to grab some ideas I appreciate it.

Comment: This also has some useful ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIYKR4sgzI8